# Updating gridview using ado.net and then changing edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I simply use commandName = "Edit" to put the gridview into edit mode. Then i use a special command ("CallUpdate") so i can update in a special function. All of this works great except after i call the update and the page refreshes IT IS STILL IN EDIT MODE. How do i work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try to set

```
yourGridView.EditIndex = -1;
```

and then to rebind it?